# How to install all security tools of Kali in other linux distros?

Tags: linux, security, fedora, kali-linux, packages

I personally like `Fedora`. On the other hand, I do some of my tasks related to security using `Kali`. Now for some reasons, I just want to use `Fedora`. I know I can install `Kali` tools manually in the `Fedora`. But, I was wondering if there is a package which contains all important `Kali` tools, and I simply install it instead of installing each `Kali` tool manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To automatically install Kali linux tools, you can use lionsec's katoolin. I'm not sure if it include every tool, but the github link is below.

**katoolin**: 
https://github.com/LionSec/katoolin

Also, there's a guide on how to do this on CentOS 7 which is redhat/fedora based.

**How To Install Kali Linux Tools On Ubuntu 16 And CentOS 7**:
http://linuxpitstop.com/install-kali-linux-tools-on-ubuntu-and-centos/

Answer (score 1):

Basically Kali linux is based on debian distribution. Hence you cannot install kali linux tools via katoolin. Katoolin uses the apt-get package manager to install the tools. Also adding Kali linux repositories in Fedora doesn't make sense.
You need to install the needed Kali tools via yum or dnf only.